# What does stp yeast stand for in an old recipe?

Tags: measurements

I saw an old recipe that called for an stp of yeast and salt...all other measurements were standard. What does stp mean?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice SE. :) Can you include a picture of the ingredients and let us know more about the recipe? I can't figure out if this is referring to 5 tsp or something altogether different. Thank you!

Comment: What is the recipe actually for? Bread?

Answer (score 11):

Could it simply be a typo? -> tsp for teaspoon?

Check if the overall proportions make sense with this, then that's probably what it was ;)

Answer (score 4):

stp, though I would usually see it as STP or stbls or something similar to distinguish it more from tsp or typos, in my experience is Short Tablespoon which was a common US term for how much yeast to use in many recipies.  It is the amount of yeast in the individual envelopes of yeast, 1/4 oz or about 2 1/4 teaspoons.  Most US home cooks learned with dry measuring cups and spoons rather than scales, so short tablespoon was shorthand for "a little less than a tablespoon" and Heaping Tablespoon was "a little more than a tablespoon" or closer to 4 teaspoons.  (Or Scant Tablespoon is another wording.)